# UWP Bind Listview items foreground to property

Tags: c#, data-binding, uwp

I want to change the foreground of certain items in a ListView based on a property of such items. If the item has the property "EsBlacklist" set to true, its foreground should be red.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <converter:ForegroundColorConverter x:Key="ForegroundConverter" x:Name="ForegroundConverter"/>
</Page.Resources>

<StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10" FontSize="24">Vehículos sin VTV</TextBlock>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.PatentesSinVtv}" Margin="10" DisplayMemberPath="Placa" 
                      SelectedItem="{x:Bind ViewModel.PatenteSeleccionada, Mode=TwoWay}"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            IsItemClickEnabled="False"
            IsSwipeEnabled="False"
            CanDragItems="False"
            SelectionMode="Single"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Grid.Row="1">
                <ListViewItem Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource ForegroundConverter}}"></ListViewItem> 
( Self should reference the item and not ListViewItem.)
            </ListView>    
</StackPanel>
```

And the converter:

```
class ForegroundColorConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            var patente = (Patente)value; //value is not a Patente but ListViewItem
            return patente.EsBlacklist ? new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red) : new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);
        }
    }
```

My problem is that "value" received in the converter is not a Patente but a ListViewItem

Answer (score 1):

> My problem is that "value" received in the converter is not a Patente but a ListViewItem

As the document of [{RelativeSource} markup extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/relativesource-markup-extension#remarks),

> {RelativeSource Self}  Produces a [Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.RelativeSource#Windows_UI_Xaml_Data_RelativeSource_Mode) value of Self. The target element should be used as the source for this binding. This is useful for binding one property of an element to another property on the same element.
> ...
>
> The Self mode is useful for binding one property of an element to another property on the same element, and is a variation on ElementName binding but does not require naming and then self-referencing the element.

Here is an example to use the `RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}`,

```
<Rectangle
  Fill="Orange" Width="200"
  Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Width}"/>
```

You can see the document to learn how to use [{RelativeSource} markup extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/relativesource-markup-extension#remarks)

You can bind the ViewModel directly to make the converter be the Patente,

```
<ListViewItem Foreground="{x:Bind ViewModel, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource ForegroundConverter}}"/>
```

Comment: But I won't go anywhere by binding the whole ViewModel, since I need to bind exactly the item in each row, since the row color depends on the item property.

Comment: @Vallo I am not too clear with your idea, but for your this issue, your problem is that "value" received in the converter is not a Patente but a ListViewItem? 
 What is the real effect you want? What is your ViewModel and Model looks like?  When you bind the ViewModel and bind the model items's property to the foreground with two way binding, usually also with a convert as what you did, it should able to implement the effect.

Comment: sorry for the delay. `ViewModel.PatentesSinVtv` is an ObservableCollection of Patente. This is bound to the ListView's ItemsSource. What I want to achieve is change the foreground of each row to the `EsBlackList` property, via the converter. If `EsBlackList` is true, the foreground of that row should be red.

Answer (score 0):

The value of foreground color is not a plain color, but a brush. 
So your converter should return `new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)`.

Comment: Alright, but my main issue is that the object "value" I'm receiving in the converter is not Patente but ListViewItem. I'm editing the question for clarity.

Comment: Ok, misunderstood you than.. Cannot test it now, but probably (Patente)((value as ListViewItem).DataContext) will work.

Answer (score 0):

You may deal with it like this:

```
<ListViewItem>
    <ListViewItem.Foreground>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{x:Bind YourColor}"/>
    </ListViewItem.Foreground>
</ListViewItem>
```

Comment: I think you should set the bind to oneway

Comment: You may if you wish to change it while running

Comment: I think if Vallo wants to bind a value onetime that I suggest that he can write it as the resource.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to implement an ItemTemplate

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="modelo:Patente">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Placa}" Foreground="{x:Bind EsBlacklist, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource ForegroundConverter}}"></TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

and the converter becomes this:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return (bool)value? new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red) : new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);
    }
```